# LEFT OUTER JOIN with CONNECT_BY_ROOT

Tags: sql, oracle10g, connect-by, hierarchical-query

I've got

```
SELECT 
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT TAXY.IDCATEGORY AS IDBRANCH
  , TAXY.IDCATEGORY
  , TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY
  , TAXY.IDCONTENT
  , TAXY.CATEGORYNAME
  , LEVEL AS LVL
FROM TAXONOMY TAXY
CONNECT BY TAXY.IDCATEGORY = PRIOR TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY
```

and want to add to each entry `CONTENTNAME` column from table `CONTENT`.

I've tried:

```
SELECT 
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT TCT.CONTENTNAME AS ENDNODECONTENTNAME
  , TAXY.IDCATEGORY
  , TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY
  , TAXY.IDCONTENT
  , TCT.CONTENTNAME 
  , TAXY.CATEGORYNAME
  , LEVEL AS LVL
FROM TAXONOMY TAXY
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTENT TCT ON TCT.IDCONTENT = TAXY.IDCONTENT
CONNECT BY TAXY.IDCATEGORY = PRIOR TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY
```

Expecting the same results, only with `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` using 1 extra column: `CONTENTNAME` from `CONTENT`, associated by `IDCONTENT`; which should be `NULL` if there is no associated content (`IDCONTENT` is `NULL`)

Instead I only get the rows where `IDCONTENT` is not `NULL`. What can I do to get those rows too?

I've also tried:

```
SELECT 
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT TAXY.IDCATEGORY AS IDBRANCH
  , TAXY.IDCATEGORY
  , TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY
  , TAXY.IDCONTENT
  , TCT.CONTENTNAME 
  , TAXY.CATEGORYNAME
  , LEVEL AS LVL
FROM TAXONOMY TAXY
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTENT TCT ON TCT.IDCONTENT = TAXY.IDCONTENT
CONNECT BY TAXY.IDCATEGORY = PRIOR TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY
```

And I've also tried

```
SELECT 
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(TAXY.CATEGORYNAME, ' \ ') AS BREADCRUMBSPATH
  , TAXY.IDCATEGORY
  , TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY
  , TAXY.IDCONTENT
  , TCT.CONTENTNAME 
  , TAXY.CATEGORYNAME
  , LEVEL AS LVL
FROM TAXONOMY TAXY
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTENT TCT ON TCT.IDCONTENT = TAXY.IDCONTENT
START WITH TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY IS NULL CONNECT BY TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY = PRIOR TAXY.IDCATEGORY
```

but I get the same results (only values where `IDCONTENT` is not `NULL`)

The most weird of it all is that the query was working as expected yesterday on development DB and now it is not. So I've created a fiddle to check if I could reproduce previous results and it works fine... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecb9d/1 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecb9d/3

What could have caused this change of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what happened (still not working) but this solution seems to work fine in both cases:

```
SELECT IDBRANCH, ENDNODEIDCONTENT, IDCATEGORY, IDPARENTCATEGORY, TAXYJ.IDCONTENT, TCT.CONTENTNAME AS ENDNODECONTENTNAME, CATEGORYNAME, LVL
FROM (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT TAXY.IDCATEGORY AS IDBRANCH
  , CONNECT_BY_ROOT TAXY.IDCONTENT AS ENDNODEIDCONTENT
  , TAXY.IDCATEGORY
  , TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY
  , TAXY.IDCONTENT
  , TAXY.CATEGORYNAME
  , LEVEL AS LVL
FROM TAXONOMY TAXY
CONNECT BY TAXY.IDCATEGORY = PRIOR TAXY.IDPARENTCATEGORY
) TAXYJ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTENT TCT ON TCT.IDCONTENT = TAXYJ.ENDNODEIDCONTENT
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecb9d/4